# Polynomials for the alternating group $A_n$

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

It is my understanding that the polynomial $f_n(x)=x^n-1$ has the Galois Group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$, group of units of order $\phi(n)$. In some sense, these are the "simplest" polynomials with that Galois Group. Is there a formula for the polynomial, say $g_n(x)$, whose Galois group is $A_n$? And, I mean $g_n(x)$ in the same sense as $f_n(x)$: that is, the "simplest" polynomials with that Galois Group of $A_n$.

Comment: a related question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238379/number-of-polynomials-whose-galois-group-is-a-subgroup-of-the-alternating-group), seems like a part of the inverse galois problem

Comment: The Galois group of $x^n-1$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$) is $(\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, the group of mulitiplicative units modulo $n$, not $C_n$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: I will update the question. Could you please provide a reference/proof/sketch-of-the-proof for that fact? Thank you.

Comment: See https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf , for example.

Comment: Note that there are distinct $n,m$ with $(Z/nZ)^\times$ and $(Z/mZ)^\times$ isomorphic (for instance, $m,n=1,2$, or $m,n=3,4$), so it's not a unique "simplest" polynomial.

Comment: In some sense the simplest polynomial with Galois group $S_n$ is the polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \sigma_ix^i$ over $\mathbf C(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n) = \mathbf C(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^{S_n}$, where $\sigma_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ elementary symmetric polynomial. Replacing $S_n$-invariants with $A_n$-invariants gives an analogous polynomial for $A_n$ (possibly over a field that is not pure transcendental ― I'm not sure).

Comment: The question was asked recently at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808650/the-cyclotomic-polynomial-analogue-for-a-n.  Generally speaking, when posting the same question on both sites this should be mentioned to avoid duplicate answers/work.

Comment: @KConrad: the other question is more specific. I posted a generalized version here in the hopes that I may be pointed to some research on the topic. I will include a reference if I post again in a situation similar to this one.

Comment: @YCor: thank you for pointing that out. Non-uniqueness is not an issue, just need one, or more, family of functions parametrized  by $n$ with $A_n$ as the Galois Group.

Comment: Schur proved that the truncated exponential polynomials $1 + x + x^2/2! + \cdots + x^n/n!$ are irreducible over $\mathbf Q$ for all $n \geq 1$ and their splitting field over $\mathbf Q$ has Galois group $A_n$ when $4 \mid n$.  When $n$ is not divisible by $4$, the Galois group is $S_n$.  The cases of $n$ being or not being divisible by $4$ corresponds to the discriminant of the polynomial being or not being a square, which is the minimial kind of information needed to know if a Galois group of an $n$th degree irreducible polynomial is or is not contained in $A_n$.

Comment: @KConrad: any available references to that work?

Comment: Just google "schur exponential galois" and you'll find a math.stackexchange page that answers your question.

Comment: @KConrad that works: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~mbaker/pdf/Coleman_GaloisNewton.pdf contains the proof in a very approachable way.

Answer (score 3):

Hermez and Salinier, [Rational trinomials with the alternating group as Galois group](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X01926538), Journal of Number Theory, Volume 90, Issue 1, September 2001, Pages 113-129 has the abstract,

For any integer $n\ge7$, we show how to explicitly build an infinite number of rational trinomals of degree $n$ whose Galois group over $\bf Q$ is isomorphic to $A_n$.